# If you’re in a different country from your eshop, in which time zone will games come out?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I am waiting for animal crossing new horizons to come out, my e-shop is British but I am currently in France, and I don’t know which time zone I should be looking at? Because in France it will come out at 12am but if it’s by the British time zone it will come out at 1am in France. Which time zone matters??